# Activiti, pass form field control value to script task variable (vice-versa)

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti

I've created a workflow utilizing the script task (exam_result as integer, exam_grade as integer, remarks as string) job. In the user task, i created a form reference (with textfield) that will handle the data entry of exam result.
The exam result text field should be passed to the exam_result variable which will be evaluated thru decision table task.

What is the best practice to send data from form field control to script task variable or vice versa?

Your help is highly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Store these values into execution variable and you should be able to access them across all the tasks.

You can use task listeners to read the form values and store them into execution variables like below.

```
execution.setVariable('exam_result',task.getVariable('exam_result'));
execution.setVariable('exam_grade',task.getVariable('exam_grade'));
execution.setVariable('remarks',task.getVariable('remarks'));
```

If you want to access them in another task listeners,

```
var examResult  = execution.getVariable('exam_result');
var examgrade = execution.getVariable('exam_grade');
var remarks= execution.getVariable('remarks');
```

This is on the delegates side, you can access them like below.

```
int examResult = (int) executionVariables.get("exam_result");
int examGrade = (int) executionVariables.get("exam_grade");
string remarks = (string) executionVariables.get("remarks");
```

Hope this helps you.

Please let me know if it not clear to you.

Comment: Hi @Muralidharan i tried using the Task Listener in the User Task symbol (under event 'complete') and added an expression to it but it didn't work.

i put this snippet inside the expression text box :
    execution.setVariable('exam_result',task.getVariable('examresult'));

still it didn't pass the textvalue of examresult to the exam_result script variable.

Comment: will you be able to share the bpmn file ?

Comment: hi @Muralidharan, i manage to change the approach as i found out that im using text control instead of the numeric control, the reason why the logical expression less than equal and the like are not showing in the drop down list. Thank you for your effort and help

Comment: You're looking comparison controls (less than, greater than) in the expression area?